# SAS reverse count within ID group

Tags: sas, countdown

I am used to creating count variables within a group where the count goes upwards +1 at each time using :

```
data objective ;
set eg ;
  count + 1 ;
  by id age ;
  if first.age then count = 1 ;
run ;
```

However I would like to do the *reverse*, i.e. where the first value of age in each id group has a value of 10 and each subsequently line has a value of -1 that of the preceding line:

```
data eg ;
  input id age desire ;
  cards;
  1 5 10
  1 4 9
  1 3 8
  1 2 7
  1 1 6
  2 10 10
  2 9 9
  2 8 8
  2 7 7
  2 6 6
  2 5 5
  2 4 4
  2 3 3
  2 2 2
  2 1 1
  3 7 10
  3 6 9
  3 5 8
  3 4 7
  3 3 6
  3 2 5
  3 1 4
  ;
run;

data objective ;
set eg ;
  count - 1 ;
  by id age ;
  if first.age_ar then count = 10 ;
run ;
```

Is there a way to do this as `count-1` is not recognised.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can add -1 without using retain as follows:

```
data objective;
    set eg;
    count + -1;
    by id descending age;
    if first.id then count = 10;
run;
```

Answer (score 1):

Try this (see comments in code for explanation):

```
data objective ;
retain count 10; /*retain last countvalue for every observation, 10 is optional as initial value*/
set eg ;
  count=count - 1 ; /*count -1 does not work, but count=count-1 with count as retainvariable*/
  by id age notsorted;/*notsorted because age is ordered descending*/
  if first.id then count = 10 ;/*not sure why you hade age_ar here, should be id to get your desired output*/
run ;
```

output:

[image]